# How to model tight coupling in UML class diagrams

Tags: uml

As far as I know it is possible to indicate tight coupling in a component diagram by using the port notation and a straight line between them. Contrary to the ball and socket notation.

[image]

How do I indicate tight coupling in class diagrams?

Comment: You don't indicate it but use it. The class design is concrete while components are more abstract.

Comment: What difference does it make if I 'indicate' tight coupling in the current state of an existing software or 'use' it while creating someting new? And, I know class diagrams are more concrete. Are you implying that coupling is not a concern on this level of granularity?

Comment: The way you implement something indicates that you have tight/loose coupling. So you do not add something like "look here: this is tight coupling".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ThomasKilian says, coupling is rather feature of code, although design decisions do influence it. Packaging and layering influence the density of the dependencies heavily. From the design perspective the tight coupling is fine as long as the classes belong to the same architecture layer

Rather then noting it in your class diagram, you may find useful the *Dependency Structure Matrix* as explained at

> Source: [Lattix's website](http://lattix.com/dependency-structure-matrix)
>
> [image]

They coined the term as far as I remember

See also:

- [uml-diagrams.org: UML Package Diagrams Overview](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/package-diagrams-overview.html)
- [Wikipedia: Multitier architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture)

Comment: You are right. Trying to document an architecture with text and UML only is just too limiting. I'll incorporate other diagrams to make my point clear.